# jquery 1.9 .browser removal scrolling in safari

Tags: jquery, safari, scroll

I have a pretty simple question.

Now that $.browser has been full removed from jQuery 1.9, how do I approach this problem:

```
    var bodyelem = $("html,body");
    if($.browser.safari) bodyelem = $("body")
    bodyelem.animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
```

People recommend using $.support, modernizer or things like now that $.browser is gone. How do I detect support for a bug/feature where it won't scroll if it is "html,body" as selector, but will if it is "body" only??

Comment: I'm mostly sure that `$("html,body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');` will work just fine cross-browser. Do you need to use `bodyelem` as a getter for `scrollTop` as well or only for setting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find quick workaround here
http://pupunzi.open-lab.com/2012/08/14/jquery-1-8-and-browser-detection/

Comment: Thanks. Shame we can't avoid using a plugin (either this one, or jQuery Migrate)

Answer (score 2):

The [jQuery upgrade guide](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/) mentions that:

> **jQuery.browser() removed**
>
> The jQuery.browser() method has been deprecated since jQuery 1.3 and is removed in 1.9. If needed, it is available as part of the jQuery Migrate plugin. We recommend using feature detection with a library such as Modernizr.

So, I guess that one obvious solution would be to use the jQuery Migrate plugin.

Comment: So it's either using a plugin that @Phoenelix has suggested or using jQuery Migrate plugin. In both cases, can't be avoided using a plugin.